# Field extensions and inverse $ \alpha$ of an element

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, book-recommendation, advice

I'm taking a second course of abstract algebra but I feel like I don't have the enough basis from the first course so it's very difficult the second one (well that's how I feel it).

For example, I have no idea how to solve this problem:

Let the extension $\frac{\mathbb Z_5[x]}{<1+x+x^2>}$: $\mathbb Z_5$ and $ \alpha$=$2+x+<1+x+x^2>$ $\in$$\frac{\mathbb Z_5[x]}{<1+x+x^2>}$.

Find $\alpha^{-1}$.

I've looking on google for this kind of exercises but I only find something like this 'Let $a=1+x^2$ in $\mathbb  Z_5[x]$, find the inverse of a'.So clearly the field doesn't has the form of $\frac{\mathbb Z_5[x]}{<1+x+x^2>}$ and a neither respect to $\alpha$.

Can somebody give an idea on how to solve the exercise?
or does anyone know about any link where there are solved exercises of this type?

Comment: Also my professor didn't solve any similar exercise like the above exercise, that's why I need help.

Comment: What textbook are you using?

Comment: (if $1+x+x^5$ is irreducible) then $\frac{\mathbb Z_5[x]}{<1+x+x^2>}$ is a finite integral domain, so you can find the inverse of $\alpha$ by looking at its powers. In particular $\alpha^{-1} = \alpha^{N-1}$ where $N$ is the number of elements in the multiplicative group. This is also the way we prove it is a field.

Comment: Not only one, many texts. One of them is Abstract algebra by Herstein @quasi But some theory it's from pdf notes I guess because I've never seen it in books

Comment: Hint: All elemennts of the quotient ring can be uniquely reduced to the form $a+bx$, where $a,b$ are constants in the base field. So assume the inverse has that form. Multiply $(2+x)(a+bx)$, set the result to $1$, reduce, and solve for $a,b$.

Comment: @quasi I agree looking at the multiplication law $(a+bx)(c+dx) = e+fx$ is a good idea for understanding what really happens here

Comment: @quasi but the multiplication will be based on the elements of the field $ \mathbb Z_5$ right? Also when you say $a$ you mean $ \alpha$?

Comment: No, a,b are unknown elements of $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: So I multiply in a normal way? @quasi

Comment: Just multiply using elementary algebra, then mod out by $x^2 + x + 1$. Then collect terms in terms of $x$, set the result to $1 + 0x$, and equate coefficients. In this context, "to mod out by $x^2 + x + 1$" just means to replace any occurrence of $x^2$ by $-x-1$.

Comment:  ok haha @quasi

Comment: I don't understand the part of 'to mod out'. I did what you told me before, to equate coefficients and I get b=1,(2b+a)=0 and 2a=0 (the last one is the constant term), is it correct? @quasi

Comment: Since $x^2 + x + 1 = 0$, you can replace any occurence of $x^2$ in the expanded product by $-x-1$. Then collect terms and equate coefficients to those of $1 +  0x$. Check your elementary algebra.  You do get two linear equations in $a,b$, but not the ones you wrote.

Comment: @quasi and that is because that's the zero element in the field $ \mathbb Z_5$/<1+x+$x^2$> right?

Comment: Yes, that's right..

Comment:  sorry, you have to have patience when you talk to me about math @quasi

Comment: I solve the system, and I get a=1/3 and b=-1/3 @quasi

Comment: What equations did you get?

Comment: Also, in $Z_5$, fractions such as $1/3$ can be simplified.

Comment: the equations are b+a=0 and 2a-b=1 @quasi

Comment: You never needed fractions -- nonzero elements of $Z_5$ have inverses in $Z_5$.

Comment: Yes, you're there -- just apply my hint about avoiding fractions.

Comment: To check your answer, multiply and reduce -- you should get $1$.

Comment: and which are the inverses I didn't know about it, I just know  $Z_5$ has 5 classes or elements and also I know how to 'convert' integer numbers from Z to $Z_5$. does that help? @quasi

Comment: Can you solve the congruence $3k \equiv 1 \pmod 5$?

Comment: yes I can @quasi

Comment: $Z_5$ is a field, so every nonzero element has an inverse, which can be found by solving an appropriate congruence mod $5$.

Comment: If $k$ solves $3k \equiv 1 \pmod 5$, then $k$ is the inverse of $3$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

Comment: Ok, so I solve the congruence first @quasi

Comment: Yes -- side work. Thus, in $Z_5$, the multiplicative inverse of $3$ is _____?

Comment: I need a few minutes.. @quasi

Comment: k=5n+2 ? , n integer @quasi

Comment: You want one of the elements of $Z_5$ as represented by $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$.

Comment: so n=0?? @quasi

Comment: In other words. if you took $Z_5 = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and made a multiplication table (mod $5$, of course), the inverse of $3$ would be _____?

Comment: then it's 1 ?? @quasi

Comment: No, $3\cdot 1$ is not congruent to $1$ mod $5$, so the inverse of $3$ is not $1$.

Comment: I don't know how to use/ made the table @quasi

Comment: Forget the table. Which of the numbers $k \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$ would be such that $3k \equiv 1 \pmod 5$

Comment: it's two right? @quasi

Comment: Yes, it's $2$. Now solve those two equations (for $a,b$) again, using inverses instead of fractions.

Comment: So a=2 now? The equation are solved I just needed to use the inverse of $a$ in the last step, where I had a=1/3=$3^{-1}$ =2 ? @quasi

Comment: Right. You correctly found $a=1/3$, $b = -1/3$, but in $Z_5$, those fractions can be replaced by appropriate inverses. Hence the inverse of $2+x$ in the original quotient ring is ________?

Comment: what? I don't know  @quasi  you tell me, give me the answer haha

Comment: But the inverse of $2+x$ is $a + bx$ -- you forced it to be so. And now you know the constants $a,b$. So ...

Comment: ah yeah I forgot it. I think the inverse is 2-2x, because the inverse of $a$ is 2. @quasi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58166/discussion-between-annelise-toft-and-quasi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, write $f(x)$ to denote the classe of $f(x)$ in $F=\frac{\mathbb{Z}_5[x]}{\langle 1+x+x^2\rangle}$. Thus $1+x+x^2=0$ in $F$. Then $1+x+x^2=0 \Leftrightarrow \\1+x=-x^2 \Leftrightarrow \\2+x=1-x^2=(1+x)(1-x)$. But $1+x=-x^2$, and we have $2+x=1-x^2=-x^2(1-x)=-x^2-x^3 \Leftrightarrow\\ 2=-x(1+x+x^2)=-x\cdot0=0$. In particular, $1=-1$ in $F$. Thus $2+x=x$ in $F$. So to find the inverse of $2+x$ is to find the inverse of $x$ in $F$. Since $1+x+x^2=0$, we have $1=-1=x(1+x)$. That is, the inverse of $2+x=x$ in $F$ is $1+x$.

Comment: @quasi what do you think?

Comment: why 1=-1 in F ?

Comment: Because $0=2=1+1$. Thus $-1=1$.

Comment: i'll accept it but first I'm gonna read it.